# WSO2AM 1.10.0 - JSONStream END_OBJECT

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm using org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamBuilder and org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamFormatter in the wso2am 1.9.1, and I don't have problems with JSON malformed, but in wso2am 1.10.0, I got this error:

```
[2016-06-30 23:50:22,489] ERROR - AnonymousListMediator javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[4,10]
Message: Unexpected symbol: END_OBJECT
org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[4,10]
Message: Unexpected symbol: END_OBJECT
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.buildNext(OMElementImpl.java:653)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSourcedElementImpl.buildNext(OMSourcedElementImpl.java:880)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMNodeImpl.getNextOMSibling(OMNodeImpl.java:122)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.getNextOMSibling(OMElementImpl.java:343)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.traverse.OMChildrenIterator.getNextNode(OMChildrenIterator.java:36)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.traverse.OMAbstractIterator.hasNext(OMAbstractIterator.java:58)
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.removeIndentations(JsonUtil.java:414)
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.removeIndentations(JsonUtil.java:421)
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.removeJsonPayload(JsonUtil.java:624)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.transform.PayloadFactoryMediator.mediate(PayloadFactoryMediator.java:158)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.transform.PayloadFactoryMediator.mediate(PayloadFactoryMediator.java:100)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:81)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:48)
    at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.AnonymousListMediator.mediate(AnonymousListMediator.java:30)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.filters.FilterMediator.mediate(FilterMediator.java:203)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:81)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:48)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:155)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.MediatorFaultHandler.onFault(MediatorFaultHandler.java:86)
    at org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler.handleFault(FaultHandler.java:102)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseMessageReceiver.receive(SynapseMessageReceiver.java:89)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:317)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:363)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:142)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Yes, I have a JSON malformed in my application, but I can't fix this now, there is a way to get the same behavior that wso2am 1.9.1? This is a bug or api manager don't have to pass JSON malformed?

**Edited**: If I use org.apache.axis2.json.JSONStreamFormatter and org.apache.axis2.json.JSONStreamBuilder, I don't have the problems, but I saw that is cause a fail on the Prototyped APIS, the GET methods don't work after change this configuraton.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You probably have wrong value in Content-Lenght header. Remove the header Content-Length.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to build the message as a Plaintext content.You can use the following builder.

```
<messageBuilder contentType="text/plain"
                        class="org.apache.axis2.format.PlainTextBuilder"/>
```